# Give 2 users full access to 1 dir fails

Tags: ubuntu

I got a user called `sc1-prymis` with this path `/home/sc1-prymis/upload`. The user is set as sftp only and is in these two groups:

- ftpaccess
- scgroup

Now I got a other user called `scmain` which has shell access. I'm using this user to start a gameserver serverfile. This user is also in the group:

- scgroup

So when I upload the serverfile with the user `sc1-prymis` there are these permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 scmain scgroup 4096 Mai 30 18:10 upload
```

And the serverfile got this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sc1-prymis sc1-prymis 43201426 Mai 30 18:11 server.jar
```

So everything is fine so far, but when I launch the serverfile (with user `scmain`) every file which got created/touched is not accessible with the user `sc1-prymis`.

Can get it working and I tried different chmod options.

Comment: You might look into what teh setgid bit does when set on a directory....

Comment: go into the upload folder and show the result of "ls -lah"

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 3 scmain     scgroup    4,0K Jun  5 04:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root       root       4,0K Mai 28 20:39 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 scmain     scmain      182 Jun  5 04:35 eula.txt
@christian drwxrwxr-x 2 scmain     scmain     4,0K Jun  5 04:35 logs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sc1-prymis sc1-prymis  42M Jun  5 04:35 server.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 scmain     scmain       60 Jun  5 04:35 server.properties

Comment: alright, got it - udo find /path/to/the/directory -type d -exec chmod 2770 '{}' \;

Answer (score 0):

Your folder `upload` allows you to everything inside. But you will have to check the files inside, whether they have the needed rights. Check that with (adapt the folder path to upload if needed):

```
ls -l ./upload/*
```

Your server.jar is not executable by the way. So you might want to give it:

```
chmod +x server.jar
```

Now, you should be able to execute it with:

```
java -jar server.jar
```